# How to download directory/file using SSH?

Tags: linux, ssh, putty

I'm using Putty SSH into a server and need to download a directory onto my computer. I tried using FileZilla, but it seems like the directory is hidden (I can't see it in FileZilla). I can see the directory in Putty, but it's in blue color. So my question:

How to download the directory?
How to set where to save the downloaded directory? example: desktop

Comment: This rather belongs to [su]. That said, [winscp](https://winscp.net/eng/index.php).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try using scp http://www.tecmint.com/scp-commands-examples/

```
scp -r username@source_host:path/to/source_folder ~/Desktop
```

If you are on windows only, winscp is a good solution http://winscp.net. Here is how to show hidden files in winscp http://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_pref_panels.

Comment: `PuTTY` runs under windows -- so scp is not an answer...

Comment: So, do the same with `pscp` instead of `scp`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin — OpenSSH runs under Windows via CygWin

Comment: @HolaSoyEduFelizNavidad it gave me this message "-bash: pscp: command not found". So I tried scp and it gave me ssh: could nopt resolve hostname online: Name or service not known. But it says that I am using root@online though. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using windows or Linux? You have to use the after the at sign the right hostname or its IP.

Comment: @HolaSoyEduFelizNavidad I did scp -r root@1.2.3.456:filename.php ~/Desktop. It asks me for password and after inputing the password, it tells me No such file or directory. I'm already at the directory where the file is located, and I made sure the file exists.. any ideas why it's saying No such file or directory?

Comment: Do you want to upload or download the file?

Comment: @HolaSoyEduFelizNavidad download a file or directory to desktop

Comment: Please specify the file/directory full path.

Comment: @HolaSoyEduFelizNavidad so even if I'm already in the directory where the file or directory that I need I still need to specify full path? Example: I am in directory A where the file I need is sandwich.jpg, so I do scp -r root@ipaddess:sandwich.jpg ~/Desktop or should it be directory A/sandwich.jpg ?

Comment: OK, so I used full path and it seems to be downloading, but I don't see it anywhere on my computer though. Downloaded a whole directory and also a single file, but nowhere to be seen. Any ideas?